# Duplicate input ids when using multiple partials in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have three partial views that are each strongly typed with separate models.  Each view contains it's own form and submits to different actions.  Some of the models contain properties with the same names and when I use the html helper methods to create the textboxes and labels, I'm ending up with duplicate html ids on the page.

**Partial _Residential View**

```
@model MyProject.Models.ResidentialModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Residential", "Transaction"))
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PersonName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonName)

  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReferenceNumber)
  @Html.LabelForm(m => m.ReferenceNumber)

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Partial _Business View**

```
@model MyProject.Models.BusinessModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Business", "Transaction"))
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BusinessName)

  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReferenceNumber)
  @Html.LabelForm(m => m.ReferenceNumber)

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Normal View**

```
<h2>Residential Transaction</h2>
@Html.Partial("_Residential")

<h2>Business Transaction</h2>
@Html.Partial("_Business")
```

The output that I'm getting looks like the following:

```
<h2>Residential Transaction</h2>
<form action="/Transaction/Residential" method="post">
  <label for="PersonName">Person Name:</label>
  <input type="text id="PersonName" name="PersonName" />

  <label for="ReferenceNumber">Reference Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="ReferenceNumber" name="ReferenceNumber" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<h2>Business Transaction</h2>
<form action="/Transaction/Business" method="post">
  <label for="BusinessName">Business Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="BusinessName" name="BusinessName" />

  <label for="ReferenceNumber">Reference Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="ReferenceNumber" name="ReferenceNumber" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Since ReferenceNumber is in both models, I'm getting a duplicate id on the page.  I figured out that i can pass an extra htmlAttributes parameter to TextBoxFor to change the id.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReferenceNumber, new { id = "ResidentialReferenceNumber" })
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReferenceNumber, new { id = "BusinessReferenceNumber" })
```

This fixes the ids on the inputs but the 'for' attribute on the labels still has the wrong value.  I looked through the various overloads for LabelFor() and unlike the TextBoxFor, there isn't an htmlAttributes property.  Is there some way that I can tell model or view to use a different id for these fields?

Comment: Um ... so it sounds like you've found the answer. What's the question?

Comment: Not sure what happened but my last paragraph was cut off.  I updated the post and added it back.

Comment: It's interesting because defining the ids actually solved a similar issue of mine where I would have multiple textboxes for a list of the same model. The issue was that editing one of the textboxes would edit the other textboxes with the same id because the textboxes were for the same property but on different instances of the model. So thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MVC helpers do not take into account that you can have multiple models in a view. All properties that have the same name will get duplicate values (one value per model).

That is, if ResidentalTransaction and BusinessModel has a `Name` property, your html form will have two `<input type="text" name="Name" />` fields.

I'm unsure of how it works if you add all models to the same viewmodel and use `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ResidentalTransaction.Id);`

Comment: This seems to fix the problem since it uses the property name given for my original models in the new wrapper model class and the property name in the original model.