# How to use login and registration views in a single page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting an issue. While using Login and Registration views in a single page.    When main view page loaded. I got an error pop up:
You are using **dublicating** email & password.
Dublicating email & password may lead to big mess.

Please note that it says **dublicating** not **duplicating**.
Have any one help me. My code is below.

My Modal is:

```
public class LoginViewModel {
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterViewModel {
   public string Email { get; set; }

   [DataType(DataType.Password)]
   public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterLoginViewModel
{
    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }
    public RegisterViewModel RegisterViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        var model = new RegisterLoginViewModel();
        model.LoginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        model.RegisterViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
   }
```

Main View:

```
@model OpenOrderFramework.Models.RegisterLoginViewModel
@Html.Partial("_RegisterForm", Model.RegisterViewModel   
      @Html.Partial("_LoginForm", Model.LoginViewModel)
```

Partial View _LoginForm:

```
 @model OpenOrderFramework.Models.LoginViewModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password)

    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
```

}
Partial View _RegisterForm:

```
@model OpenOrderFramework.Models.RegisterViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password)

    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
}
```

Comment: Potentially related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902725/duplicate-input-ids-when-using-multiple-partials-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rename your properties `Email` and `Password` from either or both of the `RegisterViewModel` and `LoginViewModel`? It's possible that is causing the problem.